# On refreshing page browser showing script

Tags: reactjs

Once I am going to refresh pages rather than main route, browser showing script/code instead of ui. Web app made using reactjs v16. I am looking for solutions. Could you please help me?

[page after refresh](https://prnt.sc/nv8q42)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class DashboardContainer extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

        }


        render() {
            return (
                <div className="right_col quick-settings" role="main">
    Dashboard
                </div>
            )
        }

    }

    export default DashboardContainer;
```

Comment: Can you upload your codes?

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. I have bundle file, may i need to upload that?

Comment: Not `bundle.js`, maybe only the `.js` files which have components you use in the view

Comment: Okay, let me share one of component file with you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you omitted the angle bracket(<>) by mistake when you used `Dashborard` component. Try this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DashboardContainer extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

}


render() {
    return (
        <div className="right_col quick-settings" role="main">
            <Dashboard />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default DashboardContainer;
```

Comment: Its an sample text not a component